# Does the bonus action attack from Polearm Master receive the bonus to attack and damage rolls from a magic weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats, dnd-beyond, weapons

If I have the Polearm Master feat and am wielding a +1 Glaive, the bonus action attack will use the same modifier as the standard attack (STR). However, does it also receive the +1 bonus from the fact that the weapon is magical?

Personally, I'd think that the full weapon is magical (not only the cutting part), so indeed the bonus attack gets a +1 as well. But in my DnDBeyond character sheet, the bonus attack does not include the magical bonus. So I wonder if this is RAW or a bug in DnDBeyond.

Comment: Do you have a link to your sheet?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### All attacks with the weapon receive the bonus to attack and damage rolls.

The description for [+1 weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weapon-1) says (DMG, pg. 213):

> You have a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.

This does not discriminate between attacks made with the Attack action and attacks made via a feature granting a bonus action, or any other distinctions we might make, so *all* attack and damage rolls receive this bonus.

If DDB is not adding the +1 to the bonus action attack, this is indeed a bug. You can work around this by customizing the bonus action attack in DDB to have a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls.

I've added a Glaive +1 to my character Poley McPoleface, and I've run into the same problem. The workaround is easy enough, see this image:

[image]

Comment: @NautArch No, your character doesn't include the right modifier either. We are not talking about the standard action; scroll down to the bonus actions and you'll see that this one does not include the magic bonus (btw unrelated: the weapon is +3/+1 but the bonus applied is +4/+2; maybe there is a typo in your homebrew implementation)

Comment: @freddieknets See the response to [my forum post](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/82684-glaive-1-not-adding-1-to-polearm-master-bonus) on DDB.

Comment: Thanks! I had also made a forum post there and got the same reply. It made me realise that also the range is wrong (should be 10ft too).